# Why does Linux program that derefrences (char*)0 not always segfault?

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, waitpid

I'm testing code that is designed to detect when a child process has segfaulted.  Imagine my surprised when this code does not always segfault:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char *p = (char *)(unsigned long)0;
  putchar(*p);
  return 0;
}
```

I'm running under a Debian Linux 2.6.26 kernel; my shell is the AT&T `ksh93` from the Debian `ksh` package, Version M 93s+ 2008-01-31.  Sometimes this program segfault but otherwise it simply terminates silently with a nonzero exit status but no message.  My signal-detecting program reports the following:

```
segfault terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault
segfault terminated by signal 53: Real-time signal 19
segfault terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault
segfault terminated by signal 53: Real-time signal 19
segfault terminated by signal 53: Real-time signal 19
segfault terminated by signal 53: Real-time signal 19
segfault terminated by signal 53: Real-time signal 19
```

Running under pure `ksh` shows that the segfault is also rare:

```
Running... 
Running... 
Running... 
Running... 
Running... 
Running... Memory fault
Running...
```

Interestingly, **`bash` correctly detects the segfault every time**.

I have two questions:

1. Can anyone explain this behavior?
2. Can anyone suggest a simple C program that will segfault reliably on every execution?  I have also tried`kill(getpid(), SIGSEGV)`, but I get similar results.

---

EDIT: **jbcreix has the answer**: my segfault detector was broken.  I was fooled because `ksh` has the same problem.  I tried with `bash` and `bash` gets it right every time.

My error was that I was passing `WNOHANG` to `waitpid()`, where I should have been passing zero.  I don't know what I could have been thinking!  One wonders what is the matter with `ksh`, but that's a separate question.

Comment: What's wrong with `exit(0)`? If you want the child to exit ...

Comment: I don't want the child to exit---I want it to segfault.  Why?  I'm building a segfault detector and I need a way to test it!

Comment: Norman, I tested it at your request.  My code works exactly as I said it would, thanks.  Not sure what is wrong on your system, maybe the parent process you are using to catch signals AND ksh?  I used kernel 2.6.28.7 to test the mmap answer.  Also works with raise(SIG_SEGV).

Comment: It is segfaulting every time and you are just failing to detect it. Even vulnerable Linux systems don't start programs with 0 mmapped by default, and that kill produced the same results, makes it quite clear. Your segfault detector needs more work. If you don't believe it munmap((void*)((quad_t)main/4096*4096),4096); usually programs like having themselves mapped the results are going to be the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Writing* to `NULL` will reliably segfault or bus error.

Sometimes an OS will map a read-only page to the zero address.  Thus, you can sometimes read from `NULL`.

Although C defines the `NULL` address as special, the 'implementation' of that special status is actually handled by the Operating System's Virtual Memory (VM) subsystem.

WINE and dosemu need to map a page at `NULL` for Windows compatibility.  See `mmap_min_addr` in the Linux kernel to rebuild a kernel which cannot do this.

`mmap_min_addr` is currently a hot topic due to a related exploit and a public flame toward Linus (of Linux fame, obviously) from Theo de Raadt, of the OpenBSD effort.

If you are willing to code the child this way, you could always call: `raise(SIGSEGV);`

Also, you can obtain a guaranteed-to-segfault pointer from:

`int *ptr_segv = mmap(NULL, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_NORESERVE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);`

Where `PROT_NONE` is the key to reserving memory which cannot be accessed.  For 32-bit Intel Linux, PAGE_SIZE is 4096.

Comment: Heh, the two biggest flamers in OSS meet, it's ... like ... the irresistible force meets the immovable object ... like ... two locomotives crashing head-on ... I wish I could sell tickets

Comment: Heath, I'd love to k now if you tested your answer on a Linux system.  I can't make it work...

Comment: Heath, I tried these and tried `raise(SIGSEGV)` too. Same problem. Unsurprising as raise(SIGSEGV) is supposed to be equivalent to kill(getpid(), SIGSEGV) on a single-threaded program. Have you tested any of your suggestions?  I would love to know if my (awful) results are reproducible.

Comment: PROT_NONE should work, it's the way Java and other systems know when to run the garbage collector. (Allocate by adding to the frontier pointer, if you get a SIGSEGV, you've gone past your space, so run a GC or get more memory.)

Comment: PROT_NONE does work.  Surprised by the claims above, I went to the trouble of verifying it.

Comment: Heath: thanks for doing the testing.  Your testing made me dig deeper, and the outcome was that I now have a bug report to file against `ksh`.  I wish I had thought of trying `bash` before posting, but I never dreamed David Korn could get this wrong :-)

Comment: @Roman - I don't really approve of that edit.  There's no reason to raise a particular signal, rather than have the reader decide which type of signal to raise.  Blech.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it doesn't have consistent behavior. I'd think that it's not as nit-picky with reading. Or something like that, though I'd probably be totally wrong.

Try writing at NULL. This seems to be consistent for me. I have no idea why you'd want to use this though. :)

```
int main()
{
    *(int *)0 = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to question number two from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) :

```
 int main(void)
 {
     char *s = "hello world";
     *s = 'H';
 }
```

Comment: I disagree with what Wikipedia says. The program *may* create a segmentation fault, but we can't be sure. The behavior is undefined IIRC.

Comment: Yes, some compilers are allowed to place literals in the (read/write) data segment.  I remember the shock when gcc made the change.  I guess I'm dating myself...